# When can the determiner 'any' be omitted?

Tags: grammar, determiners

Can I omit any in the following sentence? If I do so, Do they sound natural and grammatical?

- Yesterday I had my camera with me, but I did not take **any** photos.

Many grammar books say it is not essential to use **any**. But I don't quite understand it. Can any teacher or expert please answer this?

Answer (score 1):

Although it would be perfectly natural to omit **any** in a very wide variety of utterances, there is the possibility that its absence *might* be understood as the speaker's way of hinting at some sort of special circumstances, as a leading statement that will have a follow-up:

> I had my mobile phone with me but I didn't take pictures with it.
>   -- What *did* you do with it then?
>   I recorded some bird calls. I could hear them up in the trees but I couldn't see them.

whereas by contrast the same statement with **any** is more likely to be understood as a simple statement of fact and would not awaken  in the listener any curiosity to know more:

> I had my mobile phone with me but I didn't take any pictures with it.

That second statement is likely to be understood as "I don't have any pictures to show you."  End of story.

So, **any**  and the omission of **any** can have nuanced meaning in conversation, and there is no crude rule such as *'any' is a non-essential word that can be used or not used at will with no change of meaning*.

Comment: It also can't be dropped *at all* in certain constructions: ✘ *Pick a card, card.* Only with the use of *any* does the expression make any sense.